# jquery come back to previous value of an input with esc key

Tags: jquery, keyboard

On a lot of applications, when typing an input, the use of the esc key returns the previous value.
How can I do this with jquery.

Comment: This would involve capturing the value before the change, capturing the event that the user hits the escape key, and restoring the value to the original value.  What part about this are you having an issue with?  As it stands, this question reads as a coding request, not a request for help with an issue.

Comment: thank you, sometimes I lack ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it should do what you want.

```js
var prevValue = "";
$("#Input").focus(function() {
  prevValue = $(this).val();
}).keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 27) {
    $(this).val(prevValue);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input value="hello" id="Input" />
```

Comment: @Chamarejc Happy to help. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer that solved your problem so others know what the solution is.